# How do I use a socket proxy in C# webbrowser?

Tags: c#, sockets, browser, proxy

How do I point a socket to the proxy ip/port using the winforms webbrowser control? The standard web browser that comes with Visual C#.NET.

Please help in Visual C#.NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WebBrowser control is just a wrapper around IE. So to set proxy settings, you could change the registry key entries.

Something like this:

```
string serverName = ""; // your proxy server name
string port = ""; // your proxy port

var key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", true);
key.SetValue("ProxyServer", serverName + ":" + port);
key.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
```

Comment: I think there's something missing... RegistryKey tells me that it does not exist in current context and I might be missing a using directive or assembly reference. What's wrong?

Comment: @Jacob - `using Microsoft.Win32;`

Answer (score 1):

WebBrowser is just an interface over IE.  To set the IE proxy settings, you can hack the registry!

```
        string key = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings";
        string serverName = "";//your proxy server name;
        string port = ""; //your proxy port;
        string proxy = serverName + ":" + port;

        RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(key, true);
        RegKey.SetValue("ProxyServer", proxy);
        RegKey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
```

Comment: I think there's something missing... RegistryKey tells me that it does not exist in current context and I might be missing a using directive or assembly reference. What's wrong?

Comment: `using Microsoft.Win32;`  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey(VS.71).aspx