# How do I use a socket proxy in C# webbrowser?

Tags: c#, proxy, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use a socket proxy in C# webbrowser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246498/how-do-i-use-a-socket-proxy-in-c-webbrowser)

How do I point a socket to the proxy ip/port using the winforms webbrowser control? The standard web browser that comes with Visual C#.NET.

Please help.